# Open multiple files in folders with specific name pattern

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, filenames

I need to open automatically files and analyse their content.

I'm struggling to find a way to open them due to the fact that in each folder there is different files with different naming patterns.

**I only need to open files with a specific pattern** : "error_YYYYMMDD_xyz.json" "xyz being a number from 0 to 999.

I was using this algorithm before my need to only search specific files:

```
for folder in `ls -d $path`
do

 for file in `ls $folder`
 do
 erreur=`jq ".tot_type" $folder/$file`  

 date=`echo $folder/$file | cut -d '_' -f2 | cut -c7-8 `

 if [ \( "$erreur" > 0 \) ]
 then
      j$date=`expr ${j$date} + 1`
 fi

 done
done
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: In order to only list them you can use 
`for file in $path/$folder/error_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9]*.json; do youraction; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure to understand exactly what you try to achieve.

From what I understood, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15346038/7990687) and try to replace your second `for` loop with :

```
for file in `ls $folder | egrep 'error_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{3}\.json'`
```

It will filter the output of your ls with only files corresponding to the pattern :

`error_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{3}.json`

You can filter more precisely with a pattern which correspond only to dates starting by '20XX', month between '01' and '12' and day between '01' and '31' to restrict more the filter.

Comment: Well that was exactly what I was missing! I tried doing "for file in $folder error_????????_???.json" but I was getting errors when the folder did not contain the specific file. Thanks a lot!